# Rails 4 - Loop through deeply nested params to prevent update of password field to blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, controller, nested-attributes, parameters

In an edit form, an existing password appears in the form as blank, which seems to be the default Rails behavior.  I'm trying, however, to avoid the password (or in my case password**s**) from being updated to blank if a new password isn't entered, similar to what is described here:

[Rails Activerecord update saving unedited field as blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16620428/rails-activerecord-update-saving-unedited-field-as-blank)

The difference for me is that the password field is more deeply nested and there is more than one.

Basically what I have is a small bank transfer app where for every `:transfer` there are two `:transfer_accounts`, *source* and *destination* (transfer_accounts is a "has_many, through" join table for transfers and accounts) and both transfer accounts have an `:account` with a `:password` attribute.

My attempt was something like this at the top of the update action:

```
params[:transfer][:transfer_accounts_attributes].each do |k, v|
  v[:account_attributes][:password].delete if v[:account_attributes][:password].empty?
end
```

which didn't work.  Either password left blank is updated to blank.

**How would I iterate through the params and prevent either or both passwords from updating if they are left blank?**

Here is my controller:

```
class TransfersController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @transfer = Transfer.new
    @transfer.transfer_accounts.build(account_transfer_role: 'source').build_account
    @transfer.transfer_accounts.build(account_transfer_role: 'destination').build_account
    @valid_banks = Bank.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}  # available banks seeded in database
  end

  def index
    @transfers = Transfer.all
  end

  def show
    @transfer = resource
  end

  def create
    @transfer = Transfer.new(transfer_params)
    if @transfer.save
      redirect_to transfers_path, notice: "Transfer Created"
    else
      redirect_to transfers_path, alert:  "Transfer Not Created"
    end
  end

  def edit
    resource
    @valid_banks = Bank.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}  # available banks seeded in database
  end

  def update
    if resource.update_attributes(transfer_params)
      redirect_to transfers_path(resource),     notice: "Transfer Updated"
    else
      redirect_to edit_transfer_path(resource), alert:  "Transfer Not Updated"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    resource.destroy
  end


  private

  def resource
    @transfer ||= Transfer.find(params[:id])
  end

  def transfer_params
    params.require(:transfer).
      permit(:name, :description,
             transfer_accounts_attributes:
               [:id, :account_transfer_role,
                account_attributes:
                  [:id, :bank_id, :name, :description, :user_name,
                   :password, :routing_number, :account_number
                  ]
               ])
  end

end
```

Comment: Can you show the content of your `params` hash for a request?

Comment: Also, try using `blank?` instead of `empty?` and see if that makes any difference? `v[:account_attributes][:password].blank?`

Comment: I used blank? instead of empty?, but got the same result.

Comment: KEY: 0, VALUE: {"account_transfer_role"=>"source", "account_attributes"=>{"bank_id"=>"2", "name"=>"Joe's Checking", "description"=>"Joe's personal checking account", "user_name"=>"joechk", "password"=>"change", "account_number"=>"123456789", "routing_number"=>"1122334455", "id"=>"1"}, "id"=>"1"}
KEY: 1, VALUE: {"account_transfer_role"=>"destination", "account_attributes"=>{"bank_id"=>"3", "name"=>"Joe's Savings", "description"=>"Joe's personal savings account", "user_name"=>"joesav", "password"=>"change", "account_number"=>"098765432", "routing_number"=>"0099887766", "id"=>"2"}, "id"=>"2"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
params[:transfer][:transfer_accounts_attributes].each do |k, v|
  v[:account_attributes].delete(:password) if v[:account_attributes][:password].blank?
end
```

You have to call hash.delete, rather than delete the contents of the already blank value. Also `.blank?` is your friend, since that will take care of nil and `== ''`.

Comment: That worked perfectly!  I had a feeling I was doing what you describe, deleting a blank value, but I wasn't sure how to handle it properly. Thanks, James! (p.s. don't have the reputation yet to upvote)